# Manually cache images via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, browser-cache

So I have a site with a 3 pages that have very rich backgrounds, and I would like to know if it is possible to cache images manually via AJAX on the hompage, so that when a use goes to a new page, the large image is already loaded.

I'm using rails/turbolinks. I know there must be a way, but I was wondering if anyone knows the best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Use after page load event (to avoid the cache images slow down the current page speed time) a $.load function, like this:

```
$(document).load(function() {
    $.load("www.domain.com.br/img/image-to-pre-cache.jpg");
});
```

This should work... but, if does not work, you can also use

```
$(document).load(function() {
    $('<img/>')[0].src = "www.domain.com.br/img/image-to-pre-cache.jpg";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you could solve your problem:

**JavaScript:** There is a quite good article called [Simple Asset Management](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/games/assetmanager/) who describes a very good pre-load mechanism. It's very recommended to use it when you have a huge list of assets and you can't just download it all at once.

**CSS:** There is also [CSS technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/819788/1250728) that you describe all images that you want to preload at your CSS and leave the browser with the rest.

**HTM5:** If you need a HTML5 approach, HTML5 already has a new attribute called rel="prefetch":

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://asset.to.prefetch/imgs/sprite.png" />
```

[More about HTML5 rel prefetch](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-prefetch)

Hope it helps.