# Loading images on website load instead of page load

Tags: html, image, load

On My Website I need to load images on the index page because they are taking too long to load on other pages and it looks awful. Could somebody show me a very easy way to load images in the background of the index page so when the user clicks on the other pages the images have already loaded in their cache?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. It's about preloading with JS.

http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/image/preload.html

And this option is without JS:

[How to Preload Images without Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819336/how-to-preload-images-without-javascript)