# make HTML background always changing

Tags: javascript, html

What do I mean by 'Always changing'?
Well, for example, the Windows 8 installing screen, you see a text at the middle that says:'You can get new apps from the store', and the background are changing from red to orange to yellow to green to cyan to blue to purple then to red.
I mean, how do I do that to my HTML background with JavaScript?

Comment: What have you tried?  You can use "window.setInterval" to create a timer that calls your javascript function repeatedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simplest, effective and shortest amount of code is to do this using some CSS and JS

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    transition: background-color 2s;
}
```

Then you can set some colors in an array and call them when you need, or ever so often, or use the below function to generate random colors.

JS:

```
function randomColor() {
    return '#'+ ('000000' + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)).slice(-6)
}
```

Below is a working implementation that changes the color every 2 seconds.

```js
function randomColor() {
    return '#'+ ('000000' + (Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)).slice(-6)
}

function setColor(){
    document.getElementById('myDiv').style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    setTimeout(setColor, 2000);
}

setColor();
```

```css
#myDiv {
    height: 150px;
    transition: background-color 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have changing colors, here is a script I wrote to produce a sky effect using CSS transitions.

It does create a new div over the targeted element and apply to both a radial-gradient. Then the upper one's opacity is changed to 0, revealing the background one, while the foreground-one changed value. It does produce a smooth transition effect.

You can pass restriction colors in the form of an array, a speed variable in the form of an Number, and the id of a  target element.
You can also omit all those parameters.

I wrote it a long time ago, and it probably needs a lot of improvements, but I hope you can twirk it and make it useful for you :

```js
function Sky() {
  var sky = {};

  function rand(x) {
    if (!x) x = 1;
    return Math.round(Math.random() * x);
  }

  var isArray = function(arr) {
    if (isArray in Array) return Array.isArray(arr);
    else return arr instanceof Array;
  }

  var Chuck = function(arr) {
    var total = 0;
    arr.forEach(function(e) {
      total += e
    })
    return (total / arr.length == 0 || total / arr.length == 255);
  }

  function nightDay() {
    var RGB = sky.RGB;
    var shouldChange = Chuck(RGB);
    if (shouldChange) sky.toNight = !sky.toNight;
    for (var i = 0; i < RGB.length; i++) {
      RGB[i] += (sky.toNight) ? 10 : -10;
      if (RGB[i] < 0) {
        RGB[i] = 0;
      }
      if (RGB[i] > 255) {
        RGB[i] = 255;
      }
    }

    return "radial-gradient( " +
      "rgba(" + (rand(RGB[0]) + RGB[1]) + " ," + (rand(RGB[2]) + RGB[3]) + " ," + rand(RGB[4] + RGB[5]) + ", 0.9) " + rand(25) + "%, " +
      "rgba(" + (rand(RGB[6]) + RGB[7]) + " ," + (rand(RGB[8]) + RGB[9]) + " ," + (rand(RGB[10]) + RGB[11]) + ", 0.9) " + (rand(25) + 500) + "%) " +
      "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) repeat scroll " + rand(50) + "px " + rand(50) + "px / cover";
  }


  function changeOp(e) {
    var val = nightDay();
    var op = +sky.over.style.opacity;
    if (op > 0) {
      // First div is opaque
      if (!sky.isWebkit) {
        sky.el.style.background = val;
        if (!sky.el.style.background)
          sky.isWebkit = true;
      }
      if (sky.isWebkit)
        sky.el.style.background = "-webkit-" + val;
    } else {
      //first div is transparent
      if (!sky.isWebkit)
        sky.over.style.background = val;
      else
        sky.over.style.background = "-webkit-" + val;
    };
    sky.over.style.opacity = +!op;
  };

  function setCSS() {
    if (sky.el.parentNode) sky.el.parentNode.style.position = 'relative';
    var hasHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(sky.el.parentNode).height) > 0;
    sky.el.style.height = hasHeight ? "100%" : "100vh";
    sky.el.style.overflow = 'auto';
    sky.el.style.width = hasHeight ? "100%" : "100vh";
    sky.el.style.margin = "0";
    sky.el.style.zIndex = -2;
    sky.el.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(0,0,0);'
    sky.el.transform = 'translate3d(0,0,0);'
    sky.over = document.createElement('div');
    sky.el.insertBefore(sky.over, sky.el.firstChild);
    sky.over.setAttribute('style', 'z-index: -1; position: absolute; pointer-events:none; height:100%; width:100%; opacity:1; -webkit-transition : opacity linear ' + sky.speed / 1000 + 's; transition : opacity linear ' + sky.speed / 1000 + 's;');
    if (sky.el === document.body) {
      sky.over.style.position = 'fixed';
      sky.over.style.top = 0;
    }
  }

  sky.stop = function() {
    sky.over.removeEventListener('transitionend', changeOp, false);
  }

  sky.start = function() {
    sky.over.addEventListener('transitionend', changeOp, false);
    changeOp();
  }

  function checkLength(arr) {
    if (arr.length < 13) {
      for (var i = arr.length - 1; i < 13; i++) arr[i] = 0;
    };
  }

  function init(args) {
    for (var a = 0; a < args.length; a++) {
      switch (typeof(args[a])) {
        case "string":
          var getEl = document.getElementById(args[a]);
          sky.el = getEl || document.body;
        case "number":
          sky.speed = args[a];
        case "object":
          if (isArray(args[a])) {
            sky.RGB = args[a];
            checkLength(sky.RGB);
          };
        case "boolean":
          sky.auto = args[a];
      }
    }
    if (!sky.el) sky.el = document.body;
    if (!sky.speed) sky.speed = 9000;
    if (!sky.RGB) sky.RGB = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    if (sky.auto === undefined) sky.auto = true;
    if (sky.el.style.opacity === undefined) {
      var RGB = sky.RGB;
      sky.el.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + (rand(RGB[0]) + RGB[1]) + " ," + (rand(RGB[2]) + RGB[3]) + " ," + rand(RGB[4] + RGB[5]) + ")";
      return;
    }
    setCSS();
    if (sky.auto)
      sky.start();
    setTimeout(changeOp, 200);
  }
  init(arguments);
  return sky;
}

new Sky([255, 120, 255, 120, 255, 120, 255, 120, 255, 120, 255, 120], 5000);
```

```css
#content{width:100vw; height: 100vh}
```

```html
<div id="content">Here is some content</div>
```

Comment: Just realized I can only mark one answer. But you must spent a lot of time on this. Thanks! just don't have enough reputation to vote your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array of images and select a random one with this

```
var images = ['Imag1','Imag2','Imag3','Imag4',];
var random = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomarray.length)];
```

And then use `SetInterval` and do the whole process again every 10 seconds or 20 seconds depending on what you want.

Comment: thanks for replying my post but what I want is gradual change which is really smooth

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest learning HTML5 Canvas? You will be able to do everything you need + a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use pure CSS, i use Javascript to make this kinda of stuff only if there are no other options using CSS.

To prevent this flash on the image version you can [preload the images in CSS](https://snipplr.com/view/2122/css-image-preloader) or using [HTML5 prefetch tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819336/how-to-preload-images-without-javascript#:%7E:text=HTML5%20has%20a%20new%20way%20to%20do%20this).

```css
/* color */
.color {
  animation: colorAnimation 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes colorAnimation {
  0%   { background: red; }
  25%  { background: yellow; }
  50%  { background: blue; }
  75%  { background: green; }
  100% { background: red; }
}

/* image */
.image {
  animation: imageAnimation 10s infinite;
  background-size:     cover;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-position: center center; 
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0%   { background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg); }
  25%  { background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg); }
  50%  { background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/lights600x400.jpg); }
  75%  { background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre_wide.jpg); }
  100% { background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg); }
}



/* default block css */
.block {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  --size: 150px;
  height: var(--size);
  width: calc(var(--size) *  3);
}
```

```html
Color:
<div class="block color"></div>

Image:
<div class="block image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here us the code that you can use and customize as per your needs.

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js">       </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       var num;
       var temp=0;
       var speed=5000; /* this is set for 5 seconds, edit value to suit requirements */
       var preloads=[];

    /* add any number of images here */

    preload(
            'uploads/bg1.jpg',
            'uploads/bg2.jpg',
            'uploads/bg3.jpg'
           );

    function preload(){

    for(var c=0;c<arguments.length;c++) {
       preloads[preloads.length]=new Image();
       preloads[preloads.length-1].src=arguments[c];
      }
     }

    function rotateImages() {
       num=Math.floor(Math.random()*preloads.length);
    if(num==temp){
       rotateImages();
     }
    else {
       document.body.style.backgroundImage='url('+preloads[num].src+')';
       temp=num;

    setTimeout(function(){rotateImages()},speed);
      }
     }

    if(window.addEventListener){
       window.addEventListener('load',rotateImages,false);
     }
    else { 
    if(window.attachEvent){
       window.attachEvent('onload',rotateImages);
      }
     }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Change the images path in **preload** to your images.

Comment: thanks for spending so much time to write code on my post :) but I want Gradual change you know