# JavaScript, image doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to make **an image appear in a div** when it completes the `if` conditions but it doesn't works.

So where's the bug? Or how could the JS code work?

**JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wu6emhh7/29/**

There's the code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>BMI Rechner</h2>
    <p>Ermitteln Sie Ihren BMI</p>
    <form id="bmiForm" name="bmiForm">
        <div>
            <label for="height"><strong>Gr&ouml;sse</strong>&nbsp;[cm]
                <input id="height" onkeyup="calculateBMI();" name="height" size="6" type="text" value="170" /> </label>
            <br />
            <label for="weight"><strong>Gewicht</strong>&nbsp;[kg]
                <input id="weight" onkeyup="calculateBMI();" name="weight" size="6" type="text" value="71" /> </label>
            <br />
            <input onclick="calculateBmi()" type="button" value="BMI berechnen" />
            <br /> <strong>Ihr BMI</strong>
            <input name="bmi" size="10" type="text" />
            <br /> <strong>Einteilung:</strong>
            <input name="meaning" size="20" type="text" />
            <br />
            <input type="reset" value="Zur&uuml;cksetzen" /> </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="contener">
    <div id="Empty1"></div>
    <div id="Empty2"></div>
    <div id="Empty3"></div>
    <div id="Empty4"></div>
</div>
<div class="contener2">
    <div class="subcontener1"> 18.5 </div>
    <div class="subcontener2"> 25 </div>
    <div class="subcontener3"> 30 </div>
</div>
<div class="contener">
    <div class="untergewicht"> Untergewicht </div>
    <div class="normalgewicht"> Normalgewicht </div>
    <div class="uebergewicht"> Übergewicht </div>
    <div class="adipositas"> Adipositas </div>
</div>
```

```
function calculateBmi() {
  var weight = document.bmiForm.weight.value
    var height = document.bmiForm.height.value
    if (weight > 0 && height > 0) {
      var finalBmi = Math.round((weight / (height / 100 * height / 100)) * 10) / 10;
      document.bmiForm.bmi.value = finalBmi;
      if (finalBmi < 18.4) {
        document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Untergewicht";
        onload = function f() {
          document.getElementById("Empty1").innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/arrow-204-xxl.png"/>';
        }
      }
      if (finalBmi > 18.5 && finalBmi < 24.9) {
        document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Normalgewicht, weiter so!"
        onload = function f() {
          document.getElementById("Empty2").innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/arrow-204-xxl.png"/>';
        };
      }
      if (finalBmi > 25 && finalBmi < 29.9) {
        document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Übergewicht"
        onload = function f() {
          document.getElementById("Empty3").innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/arrow-204-xxl.png"/>';
        };
      }
      if (finalBmi > 30) {
        document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Adipositas, lassen Sie sich professional beraten"
        onload = function f() {
          document.getElementById("Empty4").innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/arrow-204-xxl.png"/>';
        };
      }
    } else {
      alert("Bitte alles ausfüllen");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `onload` supposed to be doing? The shown code never calls it, so of course it isn't doing anything. Since you never declared it I'm guessing you are trying to manipulate `window.onload`? Doing that will do nothing, the load `event` has already run when the page loaded, before you could enter anything into the form. When you reload the page the `load` event will be cleared and not run either. If you just remove the function and manipulate the element in the `if` body it will do what you appear to be trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
onload = function f() {
  document.getElementById("Empty1").innerHTML = '...';
}
```

which basically adds a [`window.onload` handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) to an already loaded page with the following simple direct assignment

```
document.getElementById("Empty1").innerHTML = '...';
```

You might also want to consider [preloading the images and using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819336/how-to-preload-images-without-javascript?rq=1) in combination with dynamically selected (see [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)) CSS classes to achieve the same effect without noticeable image loading delay.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the onload function is wrong. In addition to what le_m said: you should assign the innerHTML stuff to an onclick function (for your button: BMI). There you should update your innerHTML, otherwise you will have multiple arrow images if you click multiple times with different values.

Comment: Thx, but how? ^^'

Comment: A very simple solution would be if you clear the innerHTML like:

    document.getElementById("Empty2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("Empty3").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("Empty4").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("Empty1").innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/arrow-204-xxl.png"/>';